# Slow or no response from read pickle file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, mqtt, paho

I'm working on a project that contain a webserver that handle "time" and "traffic light" parameter and save it to a pickle file and another script load the pickle and use it for mqtt client

```
import pickle
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from datetime import datetime, date, time
from threading import Timer
date=datetime.now()
print date
try:
    while True:
        fp = open("shared.pkl", 'rb')
        shared = pickle.load(fp)
        if date < shared["now"] :
            time= shared["time"]
            light = shared["light"]
            date = shared["now"]
            fp.close()
            time= int(time)
            def pub (s):
                client.publish("traffic/light1", payload = s ,qos=0, retain=False)
            t= Timer(time , pub,[light])
            t.start()
            print time
            print light
            print date




        client = mqtt.Client()


        client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)

# Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
# handles reconnecting.
# Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
# manual interface.

        client.loop(timeout=1.0, max_packets=1)

except (EOFError, UnpicklingError):
    pass
```

it works good but sometimes it doesn't publish or doesn't read the pkl file!!
any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe more detail on what is the question? Please indicate, what you expect, what you observe. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming no MQTT errors the loop will only run once as it will block forever at the `client.loop()` call. This means it will only open and read from the file once.

Comment: `loop()` doesn't block, `loop_forever()` does.

Comment: doh! yeah, too many things going on today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at it too closely, something like the below should do the job.

Calling `client.loop()` just processes a bit of network traffic, there is no guarantee that after it has been called all traffic will have been sent. Use `loop_start()` or `loop_forever()` depending on whether you want asynchronous/blocking behaviour.

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)

client.loop_start()

print date

while True:
    try:
        fp = open("shared.pkl", 'rb')
        shared = pickle.load(fp)
        fp.close()
    except (EOFError, UnpicklingError):
        continue

    if date < shared["now"] :
        time= shared["time"]
        light = shared["light"]
        date = shared["now"]

        time= int(time)
        def pub (s):
            client.publish("traffic/light1", payload = s ,qos=0, retain=False)
        t= Timer(time , pub,[light])
        t.start()
        print time
        print light
        print date
```